# asciidoctor: How UNSET boolean attribute via document header

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

In asciidoctor I can overwrite any attribute value given on the CLI via a document header value, when I append '@' to the value on the CLI.
Example: `-a icontype=png@` is overwritten by `:icontype: svg` in the doc header. Good.

Problem: *Boolean* attributes.
How would I UNSET a **boolean** attribute given on the CLI, like `-a data-uri`.
Use Case: My .adoc renderer should by default set `data-uri`, but I would like to switch it off *sometimes* via a document header attribute.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Answer:

CLI: `-a data-uri=@`
Doc Header: `:data-uri!:`

(https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#using-attributes-set-assign-and-reference)